# After python to exe conversion botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, py2exe, boto3

I can upload data without any issue using python 2.7 interpreter on windows.
But after I compile it to exe, it shows error at line : 
`s3 = session.client('s3')`

```
import HTMLParser
import ConfigParser
# Above packages necessary because boto3 depend on them
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
# variable initialization
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3 = session.client('s3') #Error at this line
s3.upload_file(fileToUpload, bucketName, keyName)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProg.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "boto3\session.pyc", line 199, in client
  File "botocore\session.pyc", line 754, in create_client
  File "botocore\session.pyc", line 660, in get_component
  File "botocore\session.pyc", line 774, in get_component
  File "botocore\session.pyc", line 174, in <lambda>
  File "botocore\session.pyc", line 453, in get_data
  File "botocore\loaders.pyc", line 119, in _wrapper
  File "botocore\loaders.pyc", line 364, in load_data
botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: _endpoints
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because boto3 could not find its data files.

In this case *Python27\Lib\site-packages\botocore\data* contains data files. We need to instruct boto3 to search them within data folder in the same directory where our main module is. Then we need to ask py2exe to bundle referenced packages, and data files with EXE.

Provided the data files

```
copy C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\botocore\data  <project_root>\data
xcopy /s /i C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\botocore\data\s3  <project_root>\data\s3
```

Provided the `cacert.pem`

```
copy C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\botocore\vendored\requests\cacert.pem <project_root>\data
```

And then re-wrote my code as:

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session

CACERT = 'data/cacert.pem'
session = boto3.session.Session()
session._loader.search_paths.append('data') # boto3 will search for data files in the 'data' folder within current directory
s3 = session.client('s3', use_ssl=True, verify=CACERT) # cacert.pem will be used for SSL
s3.upload_file(fileToUpload, bucketName, keyName)
```

Now my python module uses resources inside the `<project_root>\data` instead of `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\botocore\data`

Finally, the `setup.py` which instructs py2exe to include all data files and referenced packages into distribution.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

aws_data_files = [
                    ('data', ['data/_endpoints.json','data/_retry.json', 'data/cacert.pem']),
                    ('data/s3/2006-03-01', ['data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json'])
                 ]
setup(
        options = {
            'py2exe': {
                'bundle_files': 1,
                'compressed': True,
                'dll_excludes':['w9xpopen.exe','crypt32.dll'],
                'packages': ['HTMLParser', 'ConfigParser', 'boto3.s3.inject'],
                }
            },
        console=['myProg.py'],
        zipfile = None,
        data_files = aws_data_files,
    )
```

Answer is extracted from this [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/275) thanks to [jamesls](https://github.com/jamesls) and [rayluo](https://github.com/rayluo).

Comment: Encountered the same problem, and your answer helped me to create *.app for Mac OS. Thanks!

Comment: **Consider up voting** if you found my answer helpful

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering my own question.

By adding following to aws-files

('data/s3/2006-03-01', ['data/s3/2006-03-01/paginators-1.json'])
('data/s3/2006-03-01', ['data/s3/2006-03-01/waiters-2.json'])

This now works as expected.